# Separate string into strings including codepoints that equate to multiple characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, emoji

I have a string with an emoji in it: `"test "`. When I use .toCharArray() on it I get `"t", "e", "s", "t", " ", "?", "?"`. I'm expecting `"t", "e", "s", "t", " ", ""`. How can I accomplish this in Java?

Comment: I believe you would need to use something different than the default UTF8 in order to see that.

Comment: A single char cannot hold an emoji, or any other supplemental codepoint, so you will need an array of ints instead.

Comment: Yeah I know that's why I said or strings.

Comment: I don't think the answers for that question satisfy mine. I have found a solution though using some information provided there. (But it still needed work)

Answer (score 0):

Because Java characters cannot hold codepoints (emoji in this case) which equate to multiple characters I used

```
string.codePoints().mapToObj(Character::toChars).map(chars -> CharBuffer.wrap(chars).toString())
```

to instead get a stream of strings which hold each codepoints characters.